# Does a bodiless function in JavaScript prevent the default of an event?

Tags: javascript, eventhandler, ontouch

I set the "passive" Parameter of a touchmove event to true and therefore can't call `e.preventDefault()` inside the function. But I need the function to prevent the default behaviour of the touchmove event when a certain condition is met, so I replaced the `ontouchmove` event with this and it works:

```
disableScroll() {
        document.ontouchmove = () => {
    }
}
```

The condition mentioned above looks like this

```
if (dragDistanceX > 3 * dragDistanceY) {
 disableScroll();
}
```

My question here is: Does this code replace the default behaviour of the event with a function that returns undefined reliably? If not then what do I have to do to prevent the default behaviour without using `e.preventDefault` or returning false?

Comment: Why would you both use `passive` and want to `preventDefault` it doesn't make sense

Comment: To keep the events default logic from blocking the execution of my custom logic. Does that make sense or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: When you set `passive` to `true` you are telling the browser that you don't want to block the default browser's behaviour and the site doesn't have to wait for your code to execute before running as usual.

Comment: [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners) say for most browsers touchmove is passive by default

Comment: also, thanks for the question! i didn't know about the passive option until now 